# Looking for good image renaming software

Tags: images, file-management

I would like a program that will traverse my folders and based on the image date taken put them in a folder structure like this

```
2011
    11
        153201001.jpg
```

or similar, any recommendations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I hope you might like to check the [Bassita's Image renaming software](http://www.bassita.com/software/). It provides various criteria too. Also, you might look at [Bulk renaming](http://www.bulkrenameutility.co.uk/Main_Intro.php). You can also look for similar type of utility softwares at [download](http://cnet.download.com)

Comment: I also found lightroom does this

Answer (score 2):

Why not whip up a script in ColdFusion to do it?  You run it locally right?  Something like this:

cfdirectory to get a list of directories starting at your /images/ folder (or whatever you call it)

Loop over that list looking for files filtering for images

Loop over that list, grabbing the file's date.

In your /newimages/ (or whatever) dir, if directory doesn't exist, create it (year of given file)
if month directory doesn't exist, create it.

cffile move or copy image into that new directory

rinse and repeat over rest of files.  You'll have to have to recursively scan each new directory it enters for more directories and files, but that wouldn't be hard.  It shouldn't take more than an hour or so to do this I figure.  Less if you're Ray Camden. :)

Comment: Yeah I considered that, might do it, nothing does exactly what I want. I wonder if ColdFusion can return image taken date.